# are locally unique pure quantum states also ground states of some local hamiltonian?

Tags: quantum-information, quantum-computer

Let $H=\sum_i H_i$ be some k-local hamiltonian with a unique ground state $|\psi>$. Then it is easily shown that $|\psi>$ is k-locally distinguishable from any other state $|\psi'>$.

Is the converse also true?

In other words assume $|\psi>$ is a pure state such that for any other pure state $|\psi'>$ there exists a subset of qubits $K$ s.t $|K| \leq k$  for a fixed $k>1$ and

$tr_{[n]\backslash K}(|\psi>) \neq tr_{[n]\backslash K}(|\psi'>)$

is it true that there exists some hamiltonian $H=\sum_i H_i$ where $H_i$ acts on at most k qubits s.t $|\psi>$ is the only ground state of $H$?

Comment: Could you spell out the converse?  (E.g., do you *restrict* to pure states which are ground states of k-local Hamiltonians, is it part of the problem to prove the *existence* of such a Hamiltonian, or is this part obvious?) -- As a side remark, you would likely increase you readership if you would explain "k-local Hamiltonian" and "k-locally indistinguishable" - currently, I have the feeling that the question is not very accessible to non-experts.

Comment: Thanks, I just edited my question to make it more understandable.

Comment: Thanks for the clarifications. However, let me ask again: It is not even obvious to me that a k-local Hamiltonian must *exist* which has $\vert\psi\rangle$ as its ground state (not necessarily unique).  Is proving the very existence of such a Hamiltonian part of the problem, or do you assume its existence and ask about uniqueness given it exists?

Comment: Yes, you are right. Proving the existence of H is part of my question.

Comment: So an example where no such Hamiltonian exists would answer your question?

Comment: Yes. I'm not sure how to characterize such "k-distinguishable" states

Comment: Have you checked if there are any connections with QMA with unique proofs?

Comment: How would such a connection look like?

Comment: I don't know, but k-local Hamiltonians with a *unique* ground state look like a natural problem for unique-QMA (and there exists work on unique-QMA). -- Thinking of it, you might additionally have to impose a spectral gap in $H$. Are you willing to make such an assumption?

Comment: If there exists a gapped hamiltonian doing the job, then it's even better. But it's harder to prove.

Comment: Besides,any counter example involves finding some k-undistinguishable state. Unfortunately I dont even now if such states exist for k>1

Comment: An example for $k$-undistinguishable states would be the $4$ ground states of the toric code (or more generally any topological fixed point model).

Comment: You are right, I meant k-distinguishable state.

Comment: Any ground state of a generic $k$-local Hamiltonian (more precisely, a non-degenerate one) is $k$-distinguishable. -- I think the real example is to prove that a state is $k$-distinguishable *without* characterizing it a ground state of a local Hamiltonian.

Comment: Yes, of course, this is exactly what I mean.

Comment: Nice problem.  Is there a motivation for that?

Answer (score 1):

The question, as I understand it, asks the following:

Consider a state $|\psi\rangle$ which is uniquely determined among all other pure states by its K-party reduced density matrices. Is it guaranteed that this state is the ground state of a K-local Hamiltonian?

First, we should note that not only is it the case that any unique pure ground state of a K-local Hamiltonian is uniquely determined among all other pure states by its K-party reduced density matrices, but it is also uniquely determined among all states (including mixed states) by its K-party reduced density matrices.

More concretely:

Define the set of n-particle quantum states which have the same K-RDMs as $\rho$ to be $A_k(\rho)$. Define the unique state with maximum entropy among all states in $A_k(\rho)$ to be the K-correlated state $\tilde{\rho}_k$. A space $V$ is called K-correlated if the maximally mixed state supported on $V$ is also K-correlated. It is observed in this [paper](http://arxiv.org/pdf/1110.6583v4.pdf) that if $V$ is the ground state space of a K-local Hamiltonian, then $V$ must be K-correlated.

Consider a quantum state $|\psi\rangle$ which is uniquely determined by its K-RDMs. If there were a K-local Hamiltonian with this quantum state as its unique ground state, then the ground state space $V$ would be one dimensional, and since $V$ must be K-correlated, the state with maximum entropy which has the same K-RDMs as $|\psi\rangle$ is just $|\psi\rangle$. This implies there are also no mixed states which share the same K-RDMs as $|\psi\rangle$.

So if there existed a pure state which was uniquely determined among all pure states by its K-RDMs, but not uniquely determined among all states (including mixed states) by its K-RDMs, then it could not be the ground state of a K-local Hamiltonian.

In this [paper](http://arxiv.org/pdf/1604.02046.pdf), posted today, I, and my collaborators, show that such states do exist. ***Thus the answer to your question is no, the converse is not true.*** Even if you show that there do not exist any other pure states with the same K-RDMs as your pure state, it is possible that it can not be the ground state of some K-local Hamiltonian.